# Typescript: how to make boolean work with discriminated union pair of true/false?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface

```
interface IData {
  importantData: string
}
```

and I want to add `isLoading` flag there. If `isLoading = false`, then the `importantData` is loaded and for sure has to be there. However, if `isLoading = true`, then `importantData` may be, or may be not there.

```
interface ILoadedData extends IData {
  isLoading: false
}

interface ILoadingData extends Partial<IData> {
  isLoading: true
}
```

So, my final type is a union of these:

```
type IDataWithLoading = ILoadedData | ILoadingData
```

If I try it works great with boolean literals

```
const a:IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: false, importantData: 'secret' })
const b:IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: false }) // the only error, nice
const c:IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: true })
const d:IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: true, importantData: 'secret' })
```

however, at compile time I don't know whether things are loading or not, so:

```
const random = Math.random() > 0.5
const e:IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: random, importantData: 'secret' }) // doesn't work
```

It complaints that types are incompatible. It kind of makes sense, since I declared cases for `true` and `false`, not for `boolean`. However, I covered every possible case for `boolean`, so I sense that TypeScript can understand that and I sense I'm doing something wrong.

If I declare `boolean` explicitly, however,

```
interface ILoadingData extends Partial<IData> {
  isLoading: boolean
}
```

it'll match `isLoading = false` with `Partial<IData>`, which is not what I want. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: 2019-05-30 with the release of TypeScript 3.5 this should be addressed by [smarter union type checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#smarter-union-type-checking).  The following applies to 3.4 and below:

---

This is a known [limitation of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289).  The compiler makes no attempt to propagate unions down into properties.  Usually such a propagation can't happen (e.g., `{a: string, b: string} | {a: number, b: number}` cannot be reduced to `{a: string | number, b: string | number}` or anything else more useful).  Even in the cases like yours where it is possible to do something, it's not cost-effective for the compiler to make the effort.  Usually cases like this come down to manually guiding the compiler through possible states.

For example, you could try this:

```
interface ILoadedDataButNotSureYet extends IData {
  isLoading: boolean;
}

interface ILoadedData extends ILoadedDataButNotSureYet {
  isLoading: false
}
```

So an `ILoadedDataButNotSureYet` does have data loaded but `isLoading` might be `true` or `false`.  Then, you can express `IDataWithLoading` as:

```
type IDataWithLoading = ILoadedDataButNotSureYet | ILoadingData;
```

This is equivalent to your original definition, but good luck trying to get the compiler to notice that.  Anyway, all the specific instances you mentioned still work:

```
const a: IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: false, importantData: 'secret' })
const b: IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: false }) // the only error, nice
const c: IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: true })
const d: IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: true, importantData: 'secret' })
```

but the last one also works:

```
const random = Math.random() > 0.5
const e: IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: random, importantData: 'secret' }) // works
```

---

You might or might not want to actually change `IDataWithLoading`. Another way to go is to keep the original definition and just slap the compiler hard enough until it understands that your code is safe.  It's not pretty though:

```
const eLit = { isLoading: random, importantData: 'secret' };
const e: IDataWithLoading = eLit.isLoading ? 
  {...eLit, isLoading: eLit.isLoading} : {...eLit, isLoading: eLit.isLoading};
// works, but is ugly
```

Yuck.  Here we are using [object spread](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#object-spread-and-rest) to copy properties, and a separate `isLoading` property to take advantage of the [type guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) that happens when you inspect `eLit.isLoading`.  The ternary operator is redundant (both the "then" and "else" clauses are identical) but the compiler gets the message that in each case the value matches `IDataWithLoading`.  As I said, yuck.

---

Finally, you could just decide that you're smarter than the compiler and use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to make it be quiet.  This has the advantage of not making you jump through hoops, with the disadvantage that the compiler isn't helping you maintain type safety here:

```
const e = { 
 isLoading: random, 
 importantData: 'secret' 
} as IDataWithLoading; // Take that, compiler!
```

---

It's up to you how to proceed.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Tweaking interfaces are certainly an option and probably the way to go, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are using Typescript for a wrong task. 
TS is about types, not values, so it cannot know

> whether things are loading or not

So your interface should look just like this

```
interface IData {
  isLoading: boolean
  importantData: string | null
}
```

**Update**

> I'm trying to make TS complain if it sees isLoading=false and no
>   importantData and do not complain if it sees isLoading=true regardless
>   of importantData presence. I am 100% sure it's possible.

Replacing this part of your code:

```
const random = Math.random() > 0.5
const e: IDataWithLoading = ({ isLoading: random, importantData: 'secret' })
```

To this:

```
const loaded = Math.random() > 0.5

let e:IDataWithLoading

if(loaded) {  
  e = { isLoading: false, importantData: 'secret' }
} else {
  e = { isLoading: true, importantData: undefined }
}
```

Should be all you need, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Well, not really: I'm trying to make TS complain if it sees `isLoading=false` and no `importantData` and do not complain if it sees `isLoading=true` regardless of `importantData` presence. I am 100% sure it's possible.

Comment: Please see the update. I am pretty sure you are over-engineering things a bit

Comment: Haha, well, I oversimplified my example to make it easier to understand. Things are a bit more complicated and going with non-dry verbose version just for slightly better type checking is not a great option... thanks for help anyway!