# Typescript: Convert object with a union key into union of objects

Tags: typescript

I have an object where one of the keys is a union of object types.

```
type A = {hello: number}
type B = {how: number}
type C = {doyou: number}

type ObjWithUnionKey = {key: A | B | C}
```

Intuitively, if I have an `ObjWithUnionKey`, there should be 3 options for what it actually is, which I could write as a union:

```
type ObjA = {key: A}
type ObjB = {key: B}
type ObjC = {key: C}

type UnionObj = ObjA | ObjB | ObjC
```

However, if I have some `ObjWithUnionKey`, I can't assign it to `UnionObj`

```
function method(a: A | B | C) {
    const thing = {key: a, foo: 4}
    const objWithUnionKey: ObjWithUnionKey = thing
    
    // This line errors!
    const unionObj: UnionObj = thing
}
```

Does anyone know why this is, and if there's a way to get around it?

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeALCAbdB7AXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4C+AUKJFAEILIpYDueRZlt90AYRZIAJlhBZCXEuWo064aAFV8ASyz4WcAD5MougfP5QA8qQBWAdVXAUK9fgDSEEMIDWLvDr0GANFAAzLFwCGV4jRSh7DTMrGxQABQBDCiTiAB4AFQA+FkyoCAAPYAh8EQBnKCT8VwB+ZA8QPEz-IJDuWSooLggAN0oIhmj8WJZh2OtbZNSM72YDbPkAwnwAY2AHKGIIWywRAAokr30fKAEASmQaKBuoVY1y4ChbVXwAc3dPKtbgvAAWWi3O4PJ5YCyTOxqDTOJqmcHxYYwlgvd7XW73fCPKArByxPDjCzIlCvN40Wg0AD0FKgmUiAHIkFAweYIOs8ABRd6vCAASWISTe0F0nLe3MyRWAAG4oCJWVhUsB5eU8LFWcAACJyhVK6VUOmU6mqSr4LBPJLlcqqN74JKkdDQRXPRQGqAMpkWNUcrn4Xn8wXS2X3bUUZVwlnrTVBpKKkO6k6M5meqAisUSgNa6NKlUeiMZmPlXV0oA

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858273/typescript-how-to-make-boolean-work-with-discriminated-union-pair-of-true-false although the latter issue has been addressed when your union is a discriminated union (which `A | B | C` is not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a typescript comiler issue.

Here is a workaround.

```
type UnionObj = Omit<UnionObjWithParam<A | B | C>, never>
```

The `Omit` will remap the type by its key and value. So it will be normalized to union key.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeALCAbdB7AXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4C+AUKJFAEILIpYDueRZlt90AYRZIAJlhBZCXEuWo064aAFV8ASyz4WcAD5MougfP5QA8qQBWAdVXAUK9fgDSEEMIDWLvDr0GANFAAzLFwCGV4jRSh7DTMrGxQABQBDCiTiAB4AFQA+FkyoCAAPYAh8EQBnKCT8VwB+ZA8QPEz-IJDuWSooLggAN0oIhmj8WJYTYht04djrW2TUjO9mA2z-fD7KbPkAwnwAY2AHKGIIWywRAAokr30fKAEASmQaKFeoPY1y4ChbVXwAc3cniqrWCeAALLQ3u9Pt8sBZZnY1BpnE1TAj4sNUSxfgCXm8PvgvlBdg5YnhphYcSg-v8aLQaAB6RlQTKRADkSCg8PMEAOeAAogC-hAAJLEJL-aC6IX-EWZIrAADcUBEfKwqWAGvKeFifOAABF1ZrtSqqOymSzVJV8FhvklyuVVP98ElSOhoFqfopLVBOdyLPrBcL1uLJRAVWqPiaKDr0byDkbo0ktbGzbcuTyg1BZfLFZHjSntbrA4nC6nymb2UA)

Comment: This works! Thank you